# Centering an html canvas causes lines to shift using angular drawing library angular-canvas-painter

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, html, canvas

Using this angular library to enable drawing on canvas on mobile devices:
https://github.com/pwambach/angular-canvas-painter

My issue is that if I center the canvas element (or it's parent element), the drawn lines "shift" to the right after touchend/mouseoff event.  That is, they appear correctly positioned as I'm drawing (they follow my finger/mouse), but on release they move to the right.

I've been trying to implement a fix along these lines:
[Why does CSS centering mess up canvas mouse coordinates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29501447/why-does-css-centering-mess-up-canvas-mouse-coordinates)

But to no avail.  Any suggestions are much appreciated.